# Unable to pass Import Value in Type:String field in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a parent stack which exports a role arn like this:

```
Outputs:
  ExportApiGatewayLambdaInnvocationRole:
     Value: !GetAtt 'ApiGatewayLambdaInnvocationRole.Arn'
     Export:
        Name:
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-ApiGatewayLambdaInnvocationRole"
```

Now, I have a child stack which tries to refer to the role arn exported from the parent stack like this:

```
StatusLambda:
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties:
     FunctionName: !Sub '${Region}-Lambda'
     Code:
       S3Bucket: !Ref PackageRepository
       S3Key: !Ref LambdaPackageLocation            
     Role:
       - Fn::ImportValue: "parent-stack-ApiGatewayLambdaInnvocationRole"
     Handler: Functions/JobStatusProvider/index.handler
     Runtime: nodejs12.x
     Timeout: 150
```

Problem: The Role field is of type String and does not accept the ImportValue function. How do I fix this? Please help

ERROR: `Value of property Role must be of type String`

Comment: Are you sure that the role is created by the time you are trying to consume it in the nested stack? Shouldn't you have a `dependsOn` attribute set in the nested stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-role) should be just `String`, but you are creating a list.

The following should rectify the issue (assuming that other things are correct):

```
StatusLambda:
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties:
     FunctionName: !Sub '${Region}-Lambda'
     Code:
       S3Bucket: !Ref PackageRepository
       S3Key: !Ref LambdaPackageLocation            
     Role: !ImportValue parent-stack-ApiGatewayLambdaInnvocationRole
     Handler: Functions/JobStatusProvider/index.handler
     Runtime: nodejs12.x
     Timeout: 150
```

Comment: Yes this fixes the issue but the problem still remains wherein I have to hard code the value. Is there a way to fix this? How to refer to a parameter

Comment: @RedBottle Hi. Which parameter? Your error was due to using list, instead of string.

Comment: Nvm. I fixed it using the full function name and combining  it with !Ref. But ur answer is correct nevertheless. Thanks